# Changed Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I accidentally delete my database from firebase, and now, create an new database and after delete google.services, dependecies, plugins, I can't pass data to new database.
Project Android/Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have the project available, you can reinitialize it by running the command `firebase init` in your project folder. if your project folder is messy and potentially corrupted from any edits, It is highly recommended to start in a new folder and migrate your work from one location to the other.

Comment: thank you, i migrate my work to the other paste and this resolve problem.